# Accessing EJB classes from Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, ejb

I have a web application built in Java 1.8 using spring and deployed on Tomcat. 
We have a third party library written in Java 1.4 using EJB.

My application needs to access the methods present in the third party library from our spring web application.

So far, i have the following done according to this link.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html

In my servlet-context.xml, i added

```
<beans:bean id="myComponent"
       class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="jndiName" value="jndi/ejb/AssociateSessionEJB"/>
        <beans:property name="businessInterface" value="com.company.serviceImpl.MyComponent"/>
    </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="loginService" class="com.company.serviceImpl.LoginServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="myComponent" ref="myComponent"/>
 </beans:bean>
```

I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myComponent' while setting bean property 'myComponent'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myComponent' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jndi/ejb/AssociateSessionEJB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jndi].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myComponent' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jndi/ejb/AssociateSessionEJB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jndi].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 52 more
```

I have not worked much with EJB before. Can you please let me know what am i missing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is here:

```
nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jndi/ejb/AssociateSessionEJB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jndi].
```

In order to fix that you need to specify correct JNDI name as a value for property `jndiName`. You have to figure out the right name under which `MyComponent` EJB is available in JNDI.

Another thing is that application using EJB cannot be deployed on Tomcat which is a a servlet-container. You need to use e.g. TomEE or other JEE app server.

Answer (score 0):

As it is explain in documentation you provided, I think the more simple is to use the ejb classes as POJO.

```
<beans:bean id="myComponent"
           class="com.company.serviceImpl.MyComponent"> 
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="loginService" class="com.company.serviceImpl.LoginServiceImpl">
            <beans:property name="myComponent" ref="myComponent"/>  
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: EJB classes are third party and we do not have control over it.

Comment: Where is deployed the EJB ?

Comment: EJB is provided to us as a jar file and we are adding that as a dependency in our project. Therefore, it is deployed with our application on Tomcat server.

Comment: So you can use it as POJO, like a simple library. You don't need to do a remote call to an JEE server. Inject the class you need in Spring classic way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to deploy and run the "library" in a compatible container then a possible solution could be, to use the remote interfaces of the the specific library, if these are available, from your Spring application running separately.